# Boolean on Objects with smooth surfaces?

Tags: modifiers

Everytime I try to subdivide or use a boolean on an object with a smooth surface I get ugly artifacts as seen here. Is there a way to punch a hole through a smooth object while keeping sharp edges?

[image]

[image]

Without Edge Split modifier (left) and after applying Edge Split modifier (right).

[image]

Comment: If not sticking to semi-automated solutions like using AutoSmooth or EdgeSplit modifiers no matter what geometry is underneath, no, there isn't. Fix the Ngons and long tiny tris/quads appeared after Boolean and you'll get more decent shading at the edges

Comment: Add edge split modifier

Answer (score -1):

Select the model Go to edit mode and press w and Remove doubles

Select the cylinder and add one subdivide

Now with the boolean modifier selecting the difference select the object.

[image]

Comment: what is a subsurface and no just adding edge split modifier does nothing at all: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b_1Uif7kvQU

Comment: sorry i mean boolean modifier and can u send the file to seen whats going wrong

Comment: Check the answer i have edited it

Comment: Sorry but you can still see the bad artifacts at the end of your gif. And why subdivide? It's supposed to be lowpoly.

Comment: There is no need to use the blend file. Look the 3rd picture in my question I have edited. I cannot get it done in a brand new project

Comment: I had to get on with the project so this is how I fixed it: http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=6c144a-1507746076.jpg It's a waste of polygons, in this case it doesn't really matter but I'm still hoping for an answer. Thanks for the help though.